# lazyload jquery different fadein based on div

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading

Lazyload allows you to fadein the images as you scroll.

Im wondering if there is any simple way to differ the fadein based on the div that's being scrolled to?

ie have the first five divs with no fadein, then have one with a fadein?

Is it possible to set the fadein interdependently of a div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You give different classes to the div containers. Moreover you can choose different animations and and effect speeds. Here are two examples for a 4 second slide down and a 1 second fade in.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("img.lazySlideDown").lazyload({
            effect : "slideDown",
            effectspeed: 4000,
        });

        $("img.lazyFadeIn").lazyload({
            effect : "fadeIn",
            effectspeed: 1000,
        });
    });
```

Just set the class and the data-original property and it should work.

```
   <img class="lazyFadeIn" data-original="img/viper_1.jpg" width="765" height="574">
```

As for what I have seen in the code, this and the option failurelimit are the only options you can set at this moment. Therefore the documentation seems outdated, since it also gives options for different events to trigger.

Notice: Although the documentation says "You can use any effect you want" not all of them worked in my tests.